# Java: Print average when 0 is pressed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I have written this simple application. Now what I want to do is to print the average result when the key **0** is pressed. This prints the average result when I put a String value as the **"getal"**.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Below you can see the code:

```
    double i;
    double number = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(input.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Next number");
            i = input.nextDouble();
            number = number + i;
            count++;
        }
    
    System.out.println("Average is " + number / (count));
```

Comment: You've already said what you wanted to do.  You only need to express it in code.  Here's a replay:  **if** zero is pressed, you want to **break** out of the loop.

Comment: I have already tried that it prints Gemiddelde is NaN

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  Please [edit] your question to be far more specific about what help you need.

Comment: i want to print the average value when the key 0 is pressed.

Comment: Are here only butthurt people? I am sure you also needed help when you were a beginner? Why the down votes? I have done everyhing right but i can't figure out where to put the if statement.

Comment: Put the if after i = input.nextDouble();

Comment: @BaSsGaz `input.nextDouble()` consumes the users input, so you can't access it after you read its value once, unless you save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is put your counting logic inside an infinite loop and then break out of that loop when the users input is equal to 0:

```
    double i;
    double getal = 0;
    int tellen  = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
            System.out.println("Volgenge getal");
            i = input.nextDouble();
            getal = getal + i;
            if(i == 0){
                //break statements end the loop
                break;
            }
            //we need to increment our count down here so the '0' doesnt count
            tellen++;
        }

    System.out.println("Gemiddelde is " + getal / (tellen));
    input.close();
}
```

There's many other ways to do this as well, it doesn't have to be with the exact logic I use. Here's another way to do it with a `do while` loop instead.

```
    double i;
    double getal = 0;
    //in this example we need to start the count at -1 since we are going to be counting the '0'
    int tellen  = -1; 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
            System.out.println("Volgenge getal");
            i = input.nextDouble();
            getal = getal + i;
            //we need to increment our count down here so the '0' doesnt count
            tellen++;
       }while(i != 0);

    System.out.println("Gemiddelde is " + getal / (tellen));
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.